# how to show 0 position dropdown by selected id top

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

how to get city by id when i pass Id its show me blank i want show the record name please check below

```
$scope.CityList = [{"CityId":1,"CityName":"London"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"Manchester"},{"CityId":3,"CityName":"Johnes"}]

    <tr ng-repeat="item in ArrTransportDetail">
    <td> <select class="form-control input-height" name="select" ng-model="item.FromCityId"
    ng-options="city as city.CityName for city in CityList ">
     <option value="">Select...</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Your `ng-options` is defining `city` as the select value. Have you tried changing it to `ng-options="city.CityId as city.CityName for city in CityList"`?

Answer (score 0):

See below example and get CityName using `city[0].CityName`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular-1.7.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cityId" placeholder="Enter your City Id" ng-keyup="cityName = searchCity(cityId)">
    </form>
    <div>{{cityName}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the controller is:

```
"use strict";

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.CityList = [{"CityId":1,"CityName":"London"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"Manchester"},{"CityId":3,"CityName":"Johnes"}];
    $scope.cityId = "";
    $scope.cityName = "";

    $scope.searchCity = function (cityId) {
        const city = $scope.CityList.filter((city) => city.CityId === parseInt(cityId));
        return (city !== 'undefined') ? city[0].CityName : "";
    };

});
```

Hope it will help you.